# Mongo - aggregate docs containing contiguous time ranges into minimum document number

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, group, contiguous

I have millions of docs containing start and end times of something they're measuring.

```
[
   {
    "start" : ISODate("2024-01-01T00:00:00"),
    "end" :   ISODate("2024-01-01T01:00:00")
   },
   {
    "start" : ISODate("2024-01-01T01:00:00"),
    "end" :   ISODate("2024-01-01T02:00:00")
   },
   {
    "start" : ISODate("2024-01-01T03:00:00"),
    "end" :   ISODate("2024-01-01T04:00:00")
   },
]
```

I would like a way of generating a result set containing only the non-contiguous blocks. For this example, that would look like:

```
[
   {
    "start" : ISODate("2024-01-01T00:00:00"),
    "end" :   ISODate("2024-01-01T02:00:00")
   },
   {
    "start" : ISODate("2024-01-01T03:00:00"),
    "end" :   ISODate("2024-01-01T04:00:00")
   },
]
```

I'm experienced with using aggregate and $group, but I can't think of a way to acheive what I need.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the expected behaviour through 2 `$setWindowFields`. For the first `$setWindowFields`, you can find the `$max` `end` field for each document in the document range of `["unbounded", -1]` that is sorted by `{start: 1}`. i.e. For a current document, you will search in the document range that has a `start` smaller than the current document and get the max `end`. We call this value `prevMax`.

Then, by comparing the `prevMax` with current document's `start`. You can determine if it should be start of a group. We call this boolean `isStart`.

After that, by using another `$setWindowFields`, you can conditionally find the `grouping` of all documents through `isStart` and in the document range of `[current, unbounded]`

Finally, using the `grouping` field to find `$max` `end` inside the grouping.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "sortBy": {
        "start": 1
      },
      "output": {
        "prevMax": {
          "$max": "$end",
          "window": {
            "documents": [
              "unbounded",
              -1
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      isStart: {
        $lt: [
          "$prevMax",
          "$start"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "sortBy": {
        "start": 1
      },
      "output": {
        "grouping": {
          "$max": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$eq": [
                  true,
                  "$isStart"
                ]
              },
              "then": "$start",
              "else": -1
            }
          },
          "window": {
            "documents": [
              "unbounded",
              "current"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: "$grouping",
      end: {
        $max: "$end"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      start: "$_id",
      end: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Kik2AsOIK5o)

Answer (score 1):

Following @ray, if we can assume there are no overlaps in the documents, there is an option to look only at the previous document and the next document for each document, not scanning all previous document for each document (twice). This can also help with matching, which can reduce the number of documents we need to `$set`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: {start 1},
      output: {
        prevMax: {$push: "$end", window: {documents: [-1, 0]}},
        nextMin: {$push: "$start", window: {documents: [0, 1]}}
      }
  }},
  {$match: {$or: [
        {$expr: {$lt: [{$first: "$prevMax"}, "$start"]}},
        {$expr: {$gt: [{$last: "$nextMin"}, "$end"]}},
        {"prevMax.1": {$exists: false}},
        {"nextMin.1": {$exists: false}}
  ]}},
  {$set: {
      isStart: {$or: [
          {$lt: [{$first: "$prevMax"}, "$start"]},
          {$eq: [{$size: "$prevMax"}, 1]}
      ]}
  }},
  {$setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: {start: 1},
      output: {grouping: {
          $max: {$cond: [{$eq: [true, "$isStart"]}, "$start", -1}},
          window: {documents: [-1, 0]}
      }}
  }},
  {$group: {_id: "$grouping", end: {$max: "$end"}}},
  {$project: {_id: 0, start: "$_id", end: 1}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Mn2dIYwiaqj)

Comment: Those are great solutions! Thank you. 
One detail I failed to mention was that I'm limited by the system's mongo version being 4.4.22, and I believe that $setWindowFields is new in v5.
Any thoughts about how I might achieve the same result with this limitation?

Comment: @SamNiconi I suspect that without MongoDB v5.0+ you will be rather limited to using `$group` to do some conditional self `$lookup`. However, for some worst cases, you might need to do a full collection lookup and that might breach [16MB document size limit](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#document-size-limit) if your collection is huge